# Unable to install pip using python

Tags: python, pip

I was reinstalling python, and trying to install pip when I got the following error:

> python install pip

> python: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you on linux

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Go to add or remove programs > click on your python version > click on edit > click on modify on that dialogue > select the check button near pip

Comment: if you have `pip` already in your scripts folder of the python installation, use `python -m pip install pip --upgrade` to update pip

Comment: @MrFuppes I get an error:
No module named pip

Comment: @Sujay it's already checked.

Comment: please refer to the Q&A linked by JohnHennig

Comment: Can you please copy the important parts from there into the comments here since it just looks like an ocean of information?

Comment: basically just download `get-pip.py` [from here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), open a command prompt in the directory where you downloaded the file to, and run `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: @MrFuppes I got this error when I did that:
 python: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: because you're running an invalid command. please take some time to *read* the comments here. then run `python get-pip.py`. There's no install flag.

Comment: I get this error now: 
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233447/discussion-between-mrfuppes-and-abhirajshri-winsome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is how you install pip. If you don't have it already, you should use the `get-pip.py` script documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Try checking my comment

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome you'll have to run the script; `python get-pip.py`

Comment: @MrFuppes I got this error: 
python: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: There isn't an `install` command that you need. on windows its just `py get-pip.py`